# Заполнения массива на Javascript?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как заполнить массив вот как на таблице?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код а дальше не знаю что делать:

```
var arr = [];
var rows = 7;
var cols = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = i;
        if (i == j ||) {
            arr[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы какие-то задания выполняете? это уже не первый вопрос заполнить массив. И каждый раз дововльно бредовый код внутри. причем специально, чтобы на SO не спрашивали, а что вы пытались сами. В целом, какой практический смысл несет этот вопрос?

Comment: Да верно выполняю задания! но я черт возьми это в первый раз делаю, я не знаю как это сделать может я туповат)), мне что то это тяжело даётся

Comment: сколько минут ты пытался сделать, прежде чем написать на SO?

Comment: да не много минут 10-15 где так

Comment: Нет слов. Приличных. 1) Вам не дают задания, которые не объясняют как решать. 2) После 10-ти минус бежать с пустяком к дядям - бросайте либо это делать, либо учится с таким настроем.

Comment: Вы правы на все 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
var rows = 7;
var cols = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = i;
        if (i == j || i == (rows - 1) / 2 || j == (cols - 1) / 2 || i == (cols - j - 1)) {
            arr[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```